# condense "gradient" family of tags

Tags: discussion, tags

**tl;dr**:  I think the "gradient" family of tags needs cleanup.

**Motivation**:
There are 17 tags with the term "gradient" in them.
https://ai.stackexchange.com/tags

Of those, 5 have zero questions associated with them.
A further 4 have 3 or less questions associated with them, and a sum of 8.
This means that more half of all those tags are informing less than 8 actual questions.

7 of them have no description.

If you look at the names, there is substantial redundancy.
What is the difference between "gradient-methods", "gradient-based-methods", policy-gradient-methods", "policy-gradient-theorem", and "gradient-based-algorithms"?

About 80% of all questions asked are in the highest 3, and 96% are in the highest 7.

**Suggestion**:
Perhaps some tag-consolidation would do good in this area?

Also, do tag-cleanup requests qualify as "feature-requests" because they "change the existing functionality"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of those have already been set up as synonyms of each other. You can see this by searching for "gradient" on [the synonyms page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

I would say that there is no substantial difference between `gradient-methods`, `gradient-based-methods`, `gradient-based-algorithms`, and `gradient-algorithms`. These have all already been set up as synonyms though, so these are fine.

Similarly, `policy-gradient-methods` and `policy-gradients` are already synonyms. They are different from the four tags mentioned above though, which is correct as far as I'm concerned. Policy gradients refers to a specific type of family of algorithms in Reinforcement Learning, whereas all the "gradient-based" things without explicit reference to "policy" can more generally just refer to pretty much anything that uses gradients (like, Stochastic Gradient Descent).

Finally, there's `policy-gradient-theorem`. This is certainly closely related to policy gradients, but in my opinion sufficiently different. There is a single specific theorem with that name, so this tag would be solely for questions about that theorem (or its proof). The `policy-gradients` tag can be more generally for any question about policy gradient algorithms (not just theoretical ones about the original theorem).

In conclusion, as far as I can see there's no need for any changes here. It's better to have the tags already set up as synonyms (such that they automatically get mapped if users type them to a single target), rather than deleting them (because then they might re-appear if users type them in again).